# Disabling the safe alarm in chapter 3 ("Enemy of the State")

Tags: mafia-2

Is there a way to disable the safe alarm during the mission where I have to steal gas ration stamps or am I stuck hauling tail from the New York's finest?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, the safe alarm can be disabled. This is also the way to earn the "The Professional" achievement.

> When entering the building, wait for one of the guards to leave to make his rounds. Sneak behind the front desk and take a left when you arrive on the other side of the room. Go to the big doors and open them. When you find a blue door, open it and proceed to the basement. Go through the other blue door, go to the left and open the second door. The safe's alarm switch is in that room. Then find the coal chute and exit through there. Back outside, climb the crates and then the awning outside to reach the roof. Go to the third window and climb through. At this point you can just do the mission as normal and leave through the window once completed.

Source: [Mafia Game Wiki](http://mafiagame.wikia.com/wiki/Enemy_of_the_State)